# Induction Proof possible here?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

The Fibonacci numbers are defined by

$F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, for $n\ge 2$.

Is it possible to prove by induction that $F_n\ge 4F_{n-3}$ for $n\ge 5$?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 $F_5 = 5 > 4 = 4 \cdot 1 = 4F_2$, so the statement is valid when $n = 5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry, I read that as $F_n = 4 F_{n - 3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to use complete (or strong) induction.

*Step 1:* Check that $F_5 \geq 4 F_2$ and $F_6 \geq 4 F_3$.

*Step 2:* Assume that the inequality $F_k \geq 4 F_{k-3}$ holds for *all integers $k$ less than $n$.* Using this assumption and the recursion $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ one can quickly show that 
$$F_{n+1} \geq 4 F_{(n+1)-3}.$$
I'll leave the pleasure to write this down to you.

*Step 3:* By the principle of complete induction, the inequality holds for all $n \geq 5$.